# How to load multiple sliders with values and tooltips with noUISlider?

Tags: nouislider

I'm trying to load multiple sliders using noUISlider and it's not working. When using the first slider, the values changes for the second and third. How do I go about refactoring the code for one slider so I can easily add additional sliders with different options?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z83oz9np/) and below is my code.

```
// noUISlider
        var actSlider = document.getElementById('act-slider');

        noUiSlider.create(actSlider, {
            start: [0, 50],
            connect: false,
            step: 1,
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                'max': 50
            },
            format: {
                to: function (value) {
                    return value + '';
                },
                from: function (value) {
                    return value.replace('', '');
                }
            }
        });

        // Connect bar
        var connectBar = document.createElement('div'),
            connectBase = actSlider.getElementsByClassName('noUi-base')[0],
            connectHandles = actSlider.getElementsByClassName('noUi-origin');

        // Give the bar a class for styling and add it to the slider.
        connectBar.className += 'connect';
        connectBase.appendChild(connectBar);

        actSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {

            // Pick left for the first handle, right for the second.
            var side = handle ? 'right' : 'left',
            // Get the handle position and trim the '%' sign.
                offset = (connectHandles[handle].style.left).slice(0, -1);

            // Right offset is 100% - left offset
            if (handle === 1) {
                offset = 100 - offset;
            }

            connectBar.style[side] = offset + '%';
        });

        // Value tooltips
        var tipHandles = actSlider.getElementsByClassName('noUi-handle'),
            tooltips = [];

        // Add divs to the slider handles.
        for (var i = 0; i < tipHandles.length; i++) {
            tooltips[i] = document.createElement('div');
            tooltips[i].className += 'value-tooltip';
            tipHandles[i].appendChild(tooltips[i]);
        }

        // When the slider changes, write the value to the tooltips.
        actSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
            tooltips[handle].innerHTML = values[handle];
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap your slider creation in a function, and call it for all elements where you want a slider created.

noUiSlider also supports `tooltips` (from version 8.1.0) and `connect` options, so you don't have to implement those yourself if you don't want to make very specific changes.

As for different options for every slider, there are several ways to do this. I've added an example using data attributes for the `step` option.

The following code initializes a slider on all elements with a `.slider` class.

```
function data ( element, key ) {
    return element.getAttribute('data-' + key);   
}

function createSlider ( slider ) {

        noUiSlider.create(slider, {
            start: [0, 50],
            connect: false,
            step: Number(data(slider, 'step')) || 1,
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                'max': 50
            },
            tooltips: true,
            connect: true,
            format: {
                to: function (value) {
                    return value + '';
                },
                from: function (value) {
                    return value.replace('', '');
                }
            }
        });
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.slider'), createSlider);
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/z83oz9np/2/) demonstrating this code.